# Auto-population of text boxes on edit from after selection from search. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a search page that returns a search from the database to a table. The table is generated from a for loop using objects stored in the ViewBag. Each row generates an edit and delete button. How would I send the information from one view to another?

I have tried JQuery to get the row but that has not led me anywhere.

Comment: Question needs more details

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could think of is to use the **asp-route-{value}** tag helper.

What you will be doing is:

1. Add the id of the object you want to populate in an anchor. This is known as an **anchor tag helper**. You can pass any info you want as a route parameter which means it will be sent as **data in the URL**.
   For instance, if we want to populate a product object in the next view you can simply send the Id of the product to the next view like this:

```cs
<a class="btn btn-warning" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-productId="@product.Id">Delete</a>
```

2. In the **controller** you need to capture the route parameter by using the same used in the anchor tag helper. For example, you will implement something like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int productId)
{
      //use the productId to populate the object

      //send the populated object back to the view

      return View(populatedOject);
}
```

3. And finally you will be able to use the populated object (model) in the view.

References:

[Microsoft docs asp-route-{value}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-route-value)